# Wrong mime type text/html with Angular, nginx, Kubernete on Docker Desktop

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, mime-types, docker-desktop

My setup:
One Docker container with nginx providing an Angular web-app.
One deployment, one service (LoadBalancer) in K8s (Docker Desktop).

nginx.conf

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;


http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server_tokens off;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

mime.types contains a huge list of mime types.

When I access the service with my browser I get

[image]

where all the mime types are set to text/html. (The browser blocks loading the js and css. "wrong mime type")

I work's without errors locally and on an AKS cluster.

How can I fix it and get the proper mime types?

Update:
**I did some more debugging and found out that the mime types are even wrong when I connect to the nginx-container and call the site with curl. Therefore it must be an nginx issue.**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my fault!
Wrong configuration because of missing ingress on local (Docker Desktop) setup.
On my AKS system I have an additional ingress which rewrites the URL (removes a part).

The URL of the resources above where like **localhost/portal/env.js**
These **localhost/portal** URLS were redirected to **index.html**.
All the CSS and JS files just contained the index.html and therefore had the proper mime type.

I just needed to add an rewrite to my *nginx.conf* to fix the issue:

```
    location /portal/ {
        rewrite ^/portal/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    }
```